# Renderizar sitios web hechos en reactjs con phathonjs desde python

Tags: python, phantomjs

Tengo un archivo llamado: **scraping_phantomjs_ajax.js** y llamo desde python y contiene:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;
var page = webPage.create();
var url = args[1]

/*Agregamos para renderizar reactjs*/
page.onInitialized = function() {
    if(page.injectJs('core-js3_4_1.1.js')){
    }    
}

page.open(url, function(status) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var content = page.content;
        console.log(status);
        phantom.exit();
    }, 200);
});
```

y tengo al .py que llamo de esta forma

```
import subprocess, sys, os
url = "https://larepublica.pe/"
url = "https://larepublica.pe/tecnologia/"
result = subprocess.check_output(['/home/alejandro/Descargas/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs', 
    'scraping_phantomjs_ajax.js', url])

print ("HTML:", result)
```

Como se ve en **scraping_phantomjs_ajax.js** he inyectado `core-js3_4_1.1.js`, esto me permite renderizar sitios con **REACTJS**, en particular en la `larepublica.pe` cuando hago petición al index sí me responde el renderizado en html correcto, pero cuando peticiono por ejemplo a otras secciones como `/tecnologia, /economia, etc`, no me devuelve el html realmente renderizado.

Obtengo este tipo de Error, desconozco lo que puede estar pasando, alguna solución?:

```
b'TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating \'f[0].name.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD")\')\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nTypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating \'f[0].name.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD")\') [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nTypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating \'f[0].name.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD")\')\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nTypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating \'f[0].name.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD")\') [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nTypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating \'f[0].name.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD")\')\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nTypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating \'f[0].name.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD")\') [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nTypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating \'f[0].name.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD")\')\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nTypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating \'f[0].name.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD")\') [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nTypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating \'f[0].name.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD")\')\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nTypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating \'f[0].name.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD")\') [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nTypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating \'f[0].name.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD")\')\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nTypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating \'f[0].name.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD")\') [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nTypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating \'f[0].name.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD")\')\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nTypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating \'f[0].name.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD")\') [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:22 in pa\nReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: Intl [object Object]\n\n  https://larepublica.pe/pf/dist/engine/react.js?d=431:31 in value\nsuccess\n'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he resuelto actualizando phantomjs2.1 a [phantomjs2.5](https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/) y actualizando core.js a [core-js3.4.1.js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) y funciona perfectamente